# SVG pixel difference in chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I want draw a diagram on a web page . I am planning to use SVG. 
I need to draw the diagram in full screen. So I am using the **`availHeight`** and **`availWidth`** to find the height and width of the client screen and plan to scale it accordingly  .

Now my screen is 1920 *1080 resolution.

For testing I drew a line as follows

```
<svg height="500" width="1920">
    <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="1900" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);" />
</svg>
```

My problem is in chrome the line overflows the screen and showing a scrollbar
but in firefox it is showing correctly with in the screen 
I need a consistent output on both browsers .

Please help me

Answer (score -1):

Why u are not makeing it responsive as an SVG? I would make a container div and make the svg responsive.

Here is a good description: 
http://soqr.fr/testsvg/embed-svg-liquid-layout-responsive-web-design.php

Comment: Thanks Peter.. its a very complex diagram and I need full control over the scale

Comment: Control by the container div (rather than the svg /if its not behaving properly?/)